# How to convert Integer into float without changing the type to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I change an integer like 10 to 10.00 in JavaScript without changing the type to string.

I know that this can be achieved by `toFixed(2)` but that returns a string to which I have to do `parseFloat` again which removed the decimal points.

```
var er = 10

console.log(parseFloat(er.toFixed(2))) // returns 10 expected: 10.00
```

Comment: er is **not an integer** ... it's the only numeric type in javascript, a `Number`

Comment: why do you need a number with zeros after the dot? for display only? why does not string work?

Comment: it's now a different question and not valid anymore, because `toFixed` is a prototype of `Number` and not of `String`.

Comment: @NinaScholz: the numbers are from an array to json objects I need to make a linechart with the number so strings do not work for me, most of the numbers in my data set have decimals but few dont and the ones that are not in decimal I would like to present them in decimal

Comment: sorry, your edits makes an answer very hard. what do you want? what do you have? and why should there be no change of type?

Comment: Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to `Number` (with unary `+`) and apply `toFixed`, to get a string again.

```js
var u = "10";            // string
    f = (+u).toFixed(2); // string

console.log(f);
```

Comment: Thanks but this returns a string I want to have a number

Comment: you can not get a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) with decimal places with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

A float has higher precision. If you want to display a specific number of digits after the decimal, it has to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this and what you wanted

```js
var er = 10;
     console.log(er.toPrecision(4).valueOf()) // returns 10 expected: 10.00
```